# How to create a button in Android Studio using kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Im trying to create a button in Android Studio using kotlin and i watched all the Youtube tutorial and when i try it on my project its dont work. i created the button on the XML file by the ID 'Button' so when i try to type `Button.setOnClickListener{}` on the MainActivity.kt its an error.

The XML

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

The MainActivity.kt

````
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    }

} ```
````

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `kotlin-android-extensions` plugin to your build.gradle file (app module)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

Comment: Thanks !! that was the problem

Comment: @GRozental great! So please accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: FYI, kotlin-android-extensions and synthetic views are deprecated. https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/11/the-future-of-kotlin-android-extensions.html